# IDE for Blackberry development on Mac ?

Tags: blackberry

Is there any plug-ins available for Eclipse to make BlackBerry applications on Mac. I have installed plugin in Eclipse for my PC.
How can I do that for my Mac?
Thanks.

Comment: Please, it is not an acronym, it is just "Mac".

Comment: Thanks for letting me know but isn't its full form is Macintosh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conversation on the BB Forum may be of use to you.  At least one of the participants claims to do all their BlackBerry development on a Mac.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/JDE-for-Mac-OS-X/m-p/64266;jsessionid=9A86026F8635F10C67A4D22D29874A13

Comment: Thanks for the link Fostah. I will try it out in this weekend.